# Why is `predict` not a generic function?

Tags: r

why is `predict` not a generic function? `isGeneric('predict')` is `FALSE` but `isGeneric('summary')` and `isGeneric('print')` is `TRUE`. All of them have methods, which can be listed with `methods('predict')` etc? So `predict` is not a generic function as described [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/genericFunction-class.html) (also obvious from looking at `class`) but still dispatches methods depending on the object passed to it (e.g. `predict.lm` or `predict.glm`). So there is a different way R dispatches methods? How can I test whether a function has methods so that all of the examples above are true? Yes, I can test the length of `methods('predict')` but that produces a warning for functions without methods.

Comment: I would think that prediction might need different parameters depending on the model, whereas summary might not.  Beyond that, it is difficult to see a single, well specified question here.  If you want to know why R is designed a certain way, one of the R developers' forums might be a better place to ask.

Comment: As an aside, many (most?) R guides recommend that you use S3 rather than S4, unless you really need S4’s unique capabilities. S3 is simpler and sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: Or use the `proto` package. Or `R.oo`. Or write your own object-oriented classes...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For starters, none of those functions are generic by your test:

```
> isGeneric('predict')
[1] FALSE
> isGeneric('summary')
[1] FALSE
> isGeneric('print')
[1] FALSE
```

Let's try again...

```
> isGeneric("summary")
[1] FALSE
> require(sp)
Loading required package: sp
> isGeneric("summary")
[1] TRUE
```

What's going on here? Well, `isGeneric` only tests for S4 generic functions, and when I start R `summary` is an S3 generic function. If a package wants to use S4 methods and classes and there already exists an S3 generic function then it can create an S4 generic.

So, initially `summary` is:

```
> summary
function (object, ...) 
UseMethod("summary")
<bytecode: 0x9e4fc08>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

which is an S3 generic. I get the `sp` package...

```
> require(sp)
Loading required package: sp
> summary
standardGeneric for "summary" defined from package "base"

function (object, ...) 
standardGeneric("summary")
<environment: 0x9f9d428>
Methods may be defined for arguments: object
Use  showMethods("summary")  for currently available ones.
```

and now `summary` is an S4 standard generic.

S3 generic methods despatch (usually) by calling `{generic}.{class}`, and this is what `UseMethod("summary")` does in the S3 `summary` generic function.

If you want to test if a function has methods for a particular class, then you probably have to test that it has an S4 method (using the functions for S4 method metadata) and an S3 method (by looking for a function called `{generic}.{class}`, such as `summary.glm`.

Great eh?

Comment: There's some code at https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3/blob/master/R/s3.r to detect S3 methods. It's pretty hard!

Answer (score 2):

My general understanding of S3 generics comes [from the R Language manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#UseMethod) where I'm lead to believe that a function `func` cannot be a generic without calling `UseMethod` in its body. So, without any fancy packages, you can use the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenpollack/9712662):

```
isFuncS3Generic <- function(func) {
  funcBody <- body(func)
  sum(grepl(pattern="UseMethod", x=funcBody)) != 0
}
```

*edit:* using your litmus test:

```
> isFuncS3Generic(print)
[1] TRUE
> isFuncS3Generic(predict)
[1] TRUE
> isFuncS3Generic(summary)
[1] TRUE
> isFuncS3Generic(glm)
[1] FALSE
```

@Hadley, I'm not really sure why this is a hard problem. Would you mind elaborating?